# Trackpad lag when scrolling through Eclipse code

Tags: touchpad, eclipse, scrolling, dell-xps

System:

- Dell XPS 15 (2018)
- Windows 10 (latest update 5th of June)
- Eclipse Java (April 2018)
- Synaptics touchpad

The problem:

When I scroll in the part of the Eclipse window that contains the code, the sidebar that shows the line numbers scrolls smoothly, but the code itself lags behind.

Probable culprit:

Since Eclipse scrolled completely smooth on my 7 year old Mac with the same project, I am pretty sure that the culprit here is the touchpad and that it is not an inherent error of Eclipse.

Tried and failed solutions suggested elsewhere:

- Changing the frequenzy with which data is sent from pad to computer didn't work out because there was no such setting
- Lowering pad sensitivity
- Disabling pinch zoom
- Changing task bar location
- Mini- and maximizing the window
- Deinstalling additional software (Color Themes and Moonlight Theme)
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Eclipse

Comment: I can confirm this in general, but: 
- it's not the trackPad, as it worked smoothly with older Eclipse versions on the same machine with an older OSX version (updated from High Sierra to Mojave)
- I have the feeling, that the line numbers along with icons (like breakpoints) lag behind the scrolling of the editor content and not the other way around.